# angularjs and Breeze.js with kendoui

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, breeze

I am learning Angular.js and Breeze.js mostly from Pluralsight course from John papa and Brian Noyes. Everything seems to work smoothly. I am trying to use widgets from Kendo UI to polish up the look of the pages. I am looking for help or guidance to see if anyone have implemented  kendo UI with Angular and Breeze. If yes, can you elaborate little on what I will need to do or any example around this. I have looked at NorthBreeze example from Breeze. I have implemented Ng-Grid and it looks good but I think I like to use Keno UI as they have more widget and have support for charts etc. Will I have to give up Breeze.js if I need to use Kendo UI? Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: Have a look at this link https://github.com/kendo-labs/breeze-kendo it has Sample projects and extensions to integrate Kendo UI with Breeze.js